# Is it possible to expose options that do not support layouts as appsetting options?

Tags: .net, app-config, nlog, appsettings, .net-4.8

Sorry if the title is a bit unclear. Perhaps I can explain myself better on an example.

NLog.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      internalLogLevel="Warn"
      internalLogFile="%userprofile%/log.log">
  
  <targets>
    <target name="mail" xsi:type="Mail"
            subject="Test subject"
            from="${appsetting:item=from}"
            to="${appsetting:item=to}"
            cc="${appsetting:item=cc}"
            bcc="${appsetting:item=bcc}"
            smtpUserName="${appsetting:item=smtpUserName}"
            smtpPassword="${appsetting:item=smtpPassword}"
            enableSsl="${appsetting:item=enableSsl}"
            secureSocketOption="${appsetting:item=secureSocketOption}"
            smtpAuthentication="${appsetting:item=smtpAuthentication}"
            smtpServer="${appsetting:item=smtpServer}"
            smtpPort="${appsetting:item=smtpPort}" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="mail" />
  </rules>

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.MailKit"/>
  </extensions>
</nlog>
```

App.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="from" value="redacted" />
    <add key="to" value="redacted" />
    <add key="cc" value="" />
    <add key="bcc" value="" />

    <add key="smtpUserName" value="redacted" />
    <add key="smtpPassword" value="redacted" />
    <add key="enableSsl" value="true" />
    <add key="secureSocketOption" value="SslOnConnect" />
    <add key="smtpAuthentication" value="Basic" />
    <add key="smtpServer" value="redacted" />
    <add key="smtpPort" value="465" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Program.cs:

```cs
using NLog;

namespace MWE
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            logger.Error("Big bad Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Rationale: NLog.config can get pretty complex and daunting, I wanted to expose some most needed and simplest options in an a bit friendlier way. (Yes, I know, the complexity of NLog.config is not evident in this example, but it's just MWE).

This will fail because certain properties of the Mail target do not accept layouts:

```
2021-06-22 13:18:00.8112 Warn Error when setting property 'EnableSsl' on 'NLog.MailKit.MailTarget' Exception: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
   at System.Boolean.Parse(String value)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, TypeCode typeCode, IFormatProvider provider)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.<>c.<BuildPropertyConversionMapper>b__9_2(String stringvalue, ConfigurationItemFactory factory)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.TryNLogSpecificConversion(Type propertyType, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory, Object& newValue)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
2021-06-22 13:18:00.8212 Warn Error has been raised. Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Error when setting property 'EnableSsl' on MailTarget ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
   at System.Boolean.Parse(String value)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, TypeCode typeCode, IFormatProvider provider)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.<>c.<BuildPropertyConversionMapper>b__9_2(String stringvalue, ConfigurationItemFactory factory)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.TryNLogSpecificConversion(Type propertyType, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory, Object& newValue)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ConfigureObjectFromAttributes(Object targetObject, ILoggingConfigurationElement element, Boolean ignoreType)
2021-06-22 13:18:00.8212 Warn Error when setting property 'SecureSocketOption' on 'NLog.MailKit.MailTarget' Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Invalid enumeration value '${appsetting:item=secureSocketOption}'.
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.TryGetEnumValue(Type resultType, String value, Object& result, Boolean flagsEnumAllowed)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
2021-06-22 13:18:00.8212 Warn Error has been raised. Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Error when setting property 'SecureSocketOption' on MailTarget ---> NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Invalid enumeration value '${appsetting:item=secureSocketOption}'.
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.TryGetEnumValue(Type resultType, String value, Object& result, Boolean flagsEnumAllowed)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ConfigureObjectFromAttributes(Object targetObject, ILoggingConfigurationElement element, Boolean ignoreType)
2021-06-22 13:18:00.8212 Warn Error when setting property 'SmtpAuthentication' on 'NLog.MailKit.MailTarget' Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Invalid enumeration value '${appsetting:item=smtpAuthentication}'.
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.TryGetEnumValue(Type resultType, String value, Object& result, Boolean flagsEnumAllowed)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
2021-06-22 13:18:00.8212 Warn Error has been raised. Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Error when setting property 'SmtpAuthentication' on MailTarget ---> NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Invalid enumeration value '${appsetting:item=smtpAuthentication}'.
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.TryGetEnumValue(Type resultType, String value, Object& result, Boolean flagsEnumAllowed)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ConfigureObjectFromAttributes(Object targetObject, ILoggingConfigurationElement element, Boolean ignoreType)
2021-06-22 13:18:00.8212 Warn Error when setting property 'SmtpPort' on 'NLog.MailKit.MailTarget' Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, TypeCode typeCode, IFormatProvider provider)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.<>c.<BuildPropertyConversionMapper>b__9_1(String stringvalue, ConfigurationItemFactory factory)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.TryNLogSpecificConversion(Type propertyType, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory, Object& newValue)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
2021-06-22 13:18:00.8212 Warn Error has been raised. Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Error when setting property 'SmtpPort' on MailTarget ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, TypeCode typeCode, IFormatProvider provider)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.<>c.<BuildPropertyConversionMapper>b__9_1(String stringvalue, ConfigurationItemFactory factory)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.TryNLogSpecificConversion(Type propertyType, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory, Object& newValue)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ConfigureObjectFromAttributes(Object targetObject, ILoggingConfigurationElement element, Boolean ignoreType)
```

So maybe let's use an intermediate variable to force the layout to expand?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      internalLogLevel="Warn"
      internalLogFile="%userprofile%/log.log">

  <variable name="from" value="${appsetting:item=from}" />
  <variable name="to" value="${appsetting:item=to}" />
  <variable name="cc" value="${appsetting:item=cc}" />
  <variable name="bcc" value="${appsetting:item=bcc}" />

  <variable name="smtpUserName" value="${appsetting:item=smtpUserName}" />
  <variable name="smtpPassword" value="${appsetting:item=smtpPassword}" />
  <variable name="enableSsl" value="${appsetting:item=enableSsl}" />
  <variable name="secureSocketOption" value="${appsetting:item=secureSocketOption}" />
  <variable name="smtpAuthentication" value="${appsetting:item=smtpAuthentication}" />
  <variable name="smtpServer" value="${appsetting:item=smtpServer}" />
  <variable name="smtpPort" value="${appsetting:item=smtpPort}" />
  
  <targets>
    <target name="mail" xsi:type="Mail"
            subject="Test subject"
            from="${from}"
            to="${to}"
            cc="${cc}"
            bcc="${bcc}"
            smtpUserName="${smtpUserName}"
            smtpPassword="${smtpPassword}"
            enableSsl="${enableSsl}"
            secureSocketOption="${secureSocketOption}"
            smtpAuthentication="${smtpAuthentication}"
            smtpServer="${smtpServer}"
            smtpPort="${smtpPort}" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="mail" />
  </rules>

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.MailKit"/>
  </extensions>
</nlog>
```

But nope - same result sadly:

```
2021-06-22 13:24:22.1235 Warn Error when setting property 'EnableSsl' on 'NLog.MailKit.MailTarget' Exception: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
   at System.Boolean.Parse(String value)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, TypeCode typeCode, IFormatProvider provider)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.<>c.<BuildPropertyConversionMapper>b__9_2(String stringvalue, ConfigurationItemFactory factory)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.TryNLogSpecificConversion(Type propertyType, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory, Object& newValue)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
2021-06-22 13:24:22.1324 Warn Error has been raised. Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Error when setting property 'EnableSsl' on MailTarget ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
   at System.Boolean.Parse(String value)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, TypeCode typeCode, IFormatProvider provider)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.<>c.<BuildPropertyConversionMapper>b__9_2(String stringvalue, ConfigurationItemFactory factory)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.TryNLogSpecificConversion(Type propertyType, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory, Object& newValue)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ConfigureObjectFromAttributes(Object targetObject, ILoggingConfigurationElement element, Boolean ignoreType)
2021-06-22 13:24:22.1324 Warn Error when setting property 'SecureSocketOption' on 'NLog.MailKit.MailTarget' Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Invalid enumeration value '${appsetting:item=secureSocketOption}'.
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.TryGetEnumValue(Type resultType, String value, Object& result, Boolean flagsEnumAllowed)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
2021-06-22 13:24:22.1324 Warn Error has been raised. Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Error when setting property 'SecureSocketOption' on MailTarget ---> NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Invalid enumeration value '${appsetting:item=secureSocketOption}'.
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.TryGetEnumValue(Type resultType, String value, Object& result, Boolean flagsEnumAllowed)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ConfigureObjectFromAttributes(Object targetObject, ILoggingConfigurationElement element, Boolean ignoreType)
2021-06-22 13:24:22.1324 Warn Error when setting property 'SmtpAuthentication' on 'NLog.MailKit.MailTarget' Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Invalid enumeration value '${appsetting:item=smtpAuthentication}'.
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.TryGetEnumValue(Type resultType, String value, Object& result, Boolean flagsEnumAllowed)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
2021-06-22 13:24:22.1324 Warn Error has been raised. Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Error when setting property 'SmtpAuthentication' on MailTarget ---> NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Invalid enumeration value '${appsetting:item=smtpAuthentication}'.
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.TryGetEnumValue(Type resultType, String value, Object& result, Boolean flagsEnumAllowed)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ConfigureObjectFromAttributes(Object targetObject, ILoggingConfigurationElement element, Boolean ignoreType)
2021-06-22 13:24:22.1324 Warn Error when setting property 'SmtpPort' on 'NLog.MailKit.MailTarget' Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, TypeCode typeCode, IFormatProvider provider)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.<>c.<BuildPropertyConversionMapper>b__9_1(String stringvalue, ConfigurationItemFactory factory)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.TryNLogSpecificConversion(Type propertyType, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory, Object& newValue)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
2021-06-22 13:24:22.1324 Warn Error has been raised. Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Error when setting property 'SmtpPort' on MailTarget ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, TypeCode typeCode, IFormatProvider provider)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.<>c.<BuildPropertyConversionMapper>b__9_1(String stringvalue, ConfigurationItemFactory factory)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.TryNLogSpecificConversion(Type propertyType, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory, Object& newValue)
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ConfigureObjectFromAttributes(Object targetObject, ILoggingConfigurationElement element, Boolean ignoreType)
```

It would seem that variables do not render layouts, but rather hold their code.

Is it therefore not possible to expose settings such as `smtpPort` as settings in `App.config`?

EDIT: I forgot: NLog version

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.7.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.MailKit" Version="3.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Only properties of the type NLog `Layout` supports assignment from `${appsetting}`. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.MailKit/blob/master/src/NLog.MailKit/MailTarget.cs

Comment: @RolfKristensen Tough :( But thanks.

Comment: You could do that from code. Is that good enough?